# WordPress Multisite Dynamic Images- Using Conditionals and Blog Name

Tags: php, image, wordpress, conditional-statements

this is my first post for help on here, and man do I really need it. This is the first time I've developed a client's site using multisite, and I'm having trouble applying the appropriate header image to it's site. There are six sites in all, and I'm using the same template for all six sites' front pages. Also, the front page is static and doesn't have a specific page selected.

The conditional below is my attempt at specifying specific images depending on which sub-site I'm on. It keeps throwing a syntax error, (sublime calls it a parse error). I would be so grateful for any help!

```
 <?php
if( get_bloginfo('All in with Laila Ali')) { 
   <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/Banner-LailaAli.jpg" />
} elseif{
   if( get_bloginfo('Jaimies 15 Minute Meals')) {
   <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/Banner-JamieOliver.jpg" />
}
} elseif{
   if( get_bloginfo('Lucky Dog')) {
   <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/Banner-LuckyDog.jpg" />
}
} elseif{
   if( get_bloginfo('Game Changers with Kevin Frazier')) {
   <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/Banner-GameChangers.jpg" />
}
} elseif{
   if( get_bloginfo('Recipe Rehab')) {
   <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/Banner-RecipeRehab.jpg" />
}
} else {
   <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/Banner-PetVet.jpg" />
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you have consecutive `<?php` tags with HTML in between them. Things like `<img src="` aren't valid php, but you are inside `<?php` tags, so PHP gives you an error.

One of the ways you can fix this is by ending the tags when you need to switch back to HTML. Like this:

```
<?php
if( get_bloginfo('All in with Laila Ali')) { 
   ?>
   <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/Banner-LailaAli.jpg" />
   <?php
} elseif{
   if( get_bloginfo('Jaimies 15 Minute Meals')) {
   ?>
   <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/Banner-JamieOliver.jpg" />
   <?php
   }
}
?>
```

Another way, is to have your PHP echo the HTML you want. Which would look something like this:

```
<?php
if( get_bloginfo('All in with Laila Ali')) { 
    echo '<img src="' . bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/Banner-LailaAli.jpg" />';
} elseif{
   if( get_bloginfo('Jaimies 15 Minute Meals')) {
       echo '<img src="'. bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/Banner-JamieOliver.jpg" />';
   }
}
?>
```

Basically, you have to remember that once you open a `<?php` tag, you can only put valid PHP until you close it with `?>`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I feel like I'm so close to getting this working, but I'm still getting an error. This time, the error reveals:                                                                         PHP syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting '('

Comment: @nickfogle It looks like your nested `if` statements don't have the closing `}`